# CSS media queries to hide and show page elements .

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm kind of new to coding with media queries, and I think I have painted myself into a corner, using too many media queries (and probably in the wrong way).

What I want to do is to hide some page elements when the width of the screen or device is smaller than 481px. So in the screenshot below, you might be able to see the couple of lines of text in the upper right corner.

[image: Screenshot of Web Site's Header area]

My problem has to do with the media queries that I've used. I am at wit's end to figure out (1) why the page elements (those two lines of text in the upper right corner) are not disappearing when the page gets smaller than 481px OR (2) why they do not appear in any larger screen/device sizes when I do manage to get the page elements to disappear.

Here is the piece of CSS code that seems to cause some issues:

```
/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px){
   /* Hiding elements for this device * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
   /*
      .poweredBy{
         display: none;
      }
   */
 }
```

With this code commented out, those two lines of text won't disappear until the window (device?) width is somewhere around 320px.

[image]

Here is the entire CSS:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
      .poweredBy{
          display: none;
      }
    }

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 321px){
      .poweredBy{
          display: none;
      }
    }

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
    @media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
        .poweredBy{
             display: none;
        }
    }



/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {}

    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {}



/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {}

/* iPad 3 ---------------- */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {}

    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {}


/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) {}

/* 960px layouts ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 960px){}

/* Large screens ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-width : 1824px) {}
```

I am using GroundworkCSS underneath, but I have added a few media queries myself -- that was most likely not an enlightened act on my behalf. So if anyone could point me in the right direction, I would be most grateful. Thanks.

Comment: I don't recommend this as a long-term fix, but does adding !important help at all? If so, it might be a selector hierarchy issue.

Comment: In my opinion you are using way to many media queries, you dont have to get as specific as you are getting. I have had success using media (max-width: 767px) { } for all mobile phone code (on occassion i may write one for max-width 500ish for smaller phones depending on the code) and media (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 768) for all tablet devices. This way you should get a lot less conflicts and wont have to use the dreaded !important

Comment: http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/ and http://designshack.net/articles/css/responsive-design-why-youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: @J McFee - You're right on the money. I've looked at Bootstrap Responsive and took their 4 media queries / breakpoints. I now have my layout working the way I wanted it to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have way to many media queries, the most you should have is three one for tablet, tablet landscape and mobile. Typically like this,

**CSS**

```
/** Mobile **/
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px), only screen and (max-device-width: 767px) {



}

/** Tablet **/
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) {



}

/** Tablet (landscape) **/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {



}
```

Comment: Totally agree, like Bootstrap does, you should have 3 media. Mobile, Tablet and Tablet Landscape. Then all the rest means more than 900px or similar.
The biggest changes usually happen between Mobile and Table Landscape and Portrait.

Comment: I disagree, for instance: I am using Angular-Flex-Layout along with my project and I have the need to create my own responsive breakpoints api to show elements based on the browser size and different breakpoints. But since I'm also using Angular-Flex-Layout I have the need to match their breakpoints which are xs, sm, md, lg, xl. To say that you never need more than 3 breakpoints is a personal opinion,not fact. Even if I were not trying to match a third parties frameworks media queries, I still may have the need to do more than sm, md, lg.

Answer (score 5):

The css code for portrait and landscape:

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
/* Style for portrait mode goes here */
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
  /* Style for landscape mode goes here */
}
```

Or, as written by Mitch Layzell,
 you can use this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px), only screen and (max-device-width: 767px) {
/** Mobile **/
}


@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) {

}

/** Tablet (landscape) **/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/** Tablet **/
}
```

If you want you can insert "(orientation : landscape)" and "max-width" or "max-width-device" together.

Comment: Great points here! again having only 3 breakpoints is a great place to start, but I can typically find the need to have more than 3 or like you have shown here, just accounting for landscape vs portrait, add a few more.