# Angular6 - How to vary .css class width based on mobile vs. browser

Tags: css, variables, mobile, desktop, angular6

I'd like my main video container to take up about 45% of the width of the window when it's in a desktop browser. However, I'd like it to be 100% of the width of the screen on mobile devices. I can achieve the result by using *ngIf=bMobile and creating two different HTML sections with two different .class sections in the .css, but I would prefer to keep the HTML simple if possible.

I have a global variable set at initialization...

```
this.globals.bMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

My .css has this class for the section...

```
.video {
    width: 45vw; /* roughly 616px */
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

My primary question: is there a way to replace "45vw" with a variable that gets set by a global bMobile variable, or some other approach to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use CSS media queries to make your app more responsive. Just change out the max-width below for different screen resolutions and devices. You can find more complex media queries for standard devices [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .video {
        width: 100vw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I was able to find a super video that helped me understand better... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KL-z9A56SQ. However, you may want to edit your answer... either change your "min-width" to "max-width" or, as I did, keep the media query with min-width and change the value in my .video to width:100vw, and change the value in your suggestion to width:45vw for it to work right. This is a different way of approaching things - and probably better, but I will need to think through the framework... thanks for showing me a different way!

Comment: Also... this other stack overflow answer really helped fill in a few blanks... go to the answer that says "You have way to many media queries" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390690/css-media-queries-to-hide-and-show-page-elements